# Photoshop doe not display some special characters

Tags: photoshop

The Photoshop CC on macOS doe not display some characters, like `⌘`， ``。

So how do I type these characters in PS?

Comment: Your question is not about a programming problem, which makes it off-topic for Stack Overflow. You would probably have a better chance at getting a useful answer, if you ask on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @LarsKristensen thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought it depends on the font you're using and if they support those symbols. They most likely do not.

You want Dingback fonts for using symbols like that I think.